# EC2 Elastic IP when attached to a subdomain in Route 53 as type 'A' is not HTTPS secured

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, elastic-ip, aws-certificate-manager

1. I've a domain `abc.org` configured on Route 53 which is https secured. I've got TLS/SSL certificate for `*.abc.org` & `abc.org` from AWS Certificate Manager. My domain is being distributed through CloudFront distribution. And, I have 2 CloudFront distributions - one for `abc.org`) and one for `www.abc.org`.
2. I've got an Elastic IP (`x.x.x.x`) address for my EC2 instance.
3. I've linked the Elastic IP (`x.x.x.x`) to a subdomain `xyz.abc.com` through a type 'A' record in AWS Route 53.
4. However, when I'm opening my subdomain `xyz.abc.com` linked to my Elastic IP in my Chrome browser, it's showing that my subdomain `xyz.abc.com` is not 'https' secured.

What additional changes do I need to make in this use case? Thank you!

Comment: Domain Names and Elastic IP addresses are totally unrelated to the protocol used during a connection. Whatever is causing your issue is unrelated to the IP address or domain name. Try using `https://xyz.abc.com`.

Comment: https://xyz.abc.com is still unsecure. I'm using a Bitnami application which is on my EC2 with an Elastic IP.

Comment: It would be due to configuration of the Bitnami application, not due to the IP address or domain name. They simply point to your server.

Comment: Thank you John! Much appreciated. I got it